# same data sent to multiple servers

Tags: javascript, rest

I hope this question is adapted.

Suppose I have a current session, that I take some form's input and that through a same javascript call, I send the data to 2 separate servers available through REST apis, does it induce any problem ? I was told this could induce a security browser alert. Is it right ?

Comment: It all depends on the circumstances. If the servers concerned do not allow CORS requests from your domain, then yes you might have a problem.

Comment: I am afraid this is a disaster, when the user's request is handled **twice**, in different servers.

Comment: But yes, as Geno says, why would you want to send the same information to two different places? What's the reason for that. Surely it only needs to be processed once? Sounds like an odd scenario. Or are you sending different parts of the form to each server, for some reason?

Comment: @ADyson the reason is quite complex, related to part of information that should be hashed and sent to a blockchain system and an the other should be sent in clear. But, we are OK that if I handle this through an other "submit" button, I won't have any type of that kind of problem ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If you're going to send it to two different places, then you can't use a single "Submit" button, as that will post back the entire page, once. After that you can't submit again. The only way around that is to set some JavaScript to handle the submit, and then make AJAX requests to each server, to send the data. Those AJAX requests will be subject to CORS restrictions.

Comment: The only _other_ way round it could be to do this job server-side. i.e. If you submit the form using a conventional postback (no JS or AJAX), then it would go to whatever URL you specify as the "action" of the form (it would be on the server which provided the page originally, normally), and the code which runs at that URL on the server would process the data, and then send the data on to the two remote servers using two further HTTP requests. Those requests, being made from a non-AJAX environment, would not be subject to CORS restrictions.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for this - besides, we are OK that there is no issue if a put 2 buttons submitting the same data one after the other ?

Comment: Did you not understand any of my explanation? If you use two buttons, then you **must** use ajax requests because otherwise, if you use a normal form submit, then your page will cease to exist at that moment, therefore the user could never press the second button, unless you re-recreate the form, auto-populate it and then make them press the second one. But that's' not user-friendly, and it's a waste of time and code. If you always want to submit to both, then there's no need for two buttons.

Comment: The issue is not the number of buttons, it's about AJAX vs non-AJAX HTTP requests, and therefore whether your requests are like to be subject to CORS restrictions. You should be easily able to find out if the servers concerned will allow CORS requests - ask the server maintainer and/or read the documentation. If it's still not clear after that, then write a quick simple test script to try it and see what happens. Far better than all this abstract speculation, you could answer your own question in a few minutes instead.

Answer (score 0):

As long as both the servers you're sending your requests to are able to serve them, there should be no issues. A browser would give you an error only if the servers are not able to serve you request due to a multitude of reasons including Bad Requests, CORS disabled or not configured for the domain making the request to server, etc.